# Como resolver o problema , o valor da variável que recebo do Input do HTML me dá o valor de NaN

Tags: javascript, html, html5

```js
function InicirContagem(){
    var vinicio = document.getElementById('txtInicio')
    var res = document.getElementById('Resposta')
    //var vn = Number.parseInt(vinicio);
    res.innerHTML=` era para aparecer o valor aqui: ${vinicio}`
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Modelo de Exercìcio</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="estilo016.css">
</head>

<body>
    <header>
        <h1> Contar Números </h1>
    </header>
    <section>
        
           inicio : <input type="number" id="txtinicio" min = '0'>
           <input type="button" value="Verificar" onclick="InicirContagem()">
           
    
        
        <div id = "Resposta">
                Preparando a contagem...

        </div>
    </section>
    <footer> <p>&copy; GrauTécnico INFO 03.</p>
    </footer>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript"  src="script016.js"></script>
    
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Tá aparecendo `null` e não NaN.

Answer (score 0):

Na sua função "InicirContagem", tem um problema na hora de pegar o valor do input, porque o nome do campo está diferente do ID do formulário. Altere a função para ficar da seguinte forma:

```js
function InicirContagem(){
    var vinicio = document.getElementById('txtinicio').value;
    var res = document.getElementById('Resposta')
    //var vn = Number.parseInt(vinicio);
    res.innerHTML=` era para aparecer o valor aqui: ${vinicio}`
}
```

Comment: Agora corrigi e aparece dessa forma   res.innerHTML=` era para aparecer o valor aqui: [object HTMLInputElement]

Comment: @maykon vc deve ter esquecido de colocar `.value` no `var vinicio = document.getElementById('txtinicio').value;`.

Answer (score 0):

```
function InicirContagem(){
    var vinicio = document.getElementById('txtinicio').value;
    var res = document.getElementById('Resposta')
    var vn = Number.parseInt(vinicio, 10);
    res.innerHTML = (` era para aparecer o valor aqui: ${vn}`);
```

A sua variável vinicio estava apenas selecionando o campo e não pegando o valor dele.

Number.parseInt espera 2 parâmetros.
Veja mais detalhes aqui:
[MDN parseInt](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt)

Na última linha, você passava para o campo resposta o valor da variável vinicio, quando deveria passar o valor da variável vn.

Tenha atenção ao código, utilize Eventos ao invés de chamar a função diretamente no HTML e utilize let ou const ao invés de var e utilize camelCase para as variáveis e funções ;-)

Certamente dá para melhorar e otimizar esse código.